# python jenkins api quiet_down() not working

Tags: python, jenkins

I am trying to send quiet_down() using python-jenkins api but I get the following messages and the server doesn't go into shutdown mode.

> > > import jenkins
> > >       server = jenkins.Jenkins('serveraddress', username='someuser', password='somepassword')
> > >       server.quiet_down()
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkins__init__.py", line 1642, in quiet_
> > >       down
> > >           self.jenkins_open(request)
> > >         File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkins__init__.py", line 431, in jenkins
> > >       _open
> > >           response = urlopen(req, timeout=self.timeout).read()
> > >         File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
> > >           return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
> > >         File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 435, in open
> > >           response = meth(req, response)
> > >         File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
> > >           'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
> > >         File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 473, in error
> > >           return self._call_chain(*args)
> > >         File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
> > >           result = func(*args)
> > >         File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
> > >           raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
> > >       urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed

I have checked and I'm being authenticated correctly and I do have all the rights on it. Jenkins version is 2.7.4.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.